# Set progressbar position

Tags: android, timestamp, progress-bar

I need progress bar witch position depends on two timestamp values in millis, so it depends on future timestamp, past timestamp and current timestamp.

For example, I have timestamp of 08:46:11 30.06.2019 and 10:46:11 30.06.2019. But current time is 09:46:11 30.06.2019, so now progressbar should be filled on 50% and going up to 100 until 10:46:11 30.06.2019

I have tried the next code but now I have understood that using CountDownTimer is useless and it is not for my task which described above:

```
private void progressBar(){
            prBar.setProgress(i);
            mCountDownTimer=new CountDownTimer(ltimestampStop * 1000,ltimestampStart * 1000) {

                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    Log.v("Log_tag", "Tick of Progress"+ i+ millisUntilFinished);
                    i++;
                    int Start = ltimestampStart.intValue();
                    int Stop = ltimestampStop.intValue();
                    prBar.setProgress((int)i*100/(Stop/Start));

                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    //Do what you want
                    i++;
                    prBar.setProgress(100);
                }
            };
            mCountDownTimer.start();
        }
```

So what should I done for creating progressbar on certain position which depends on future time, past time and present time?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to following:

```
long startTimeInMillis = ...;     // 08:46:11 30.06.2019
long stopTimeInMillis = ...;      // 10:46:11 30.06.2019
long currentTimeInMillis = ...;   // 09:46:11 30.06.2019
long totalTimeInMilis = stopTimeInMillis - startTimeInMillis;

// Standart logic
long remainingTimeInMillis = stopTimeInMillis - currentTimeInMillis;
// But this line assures remaining time is not greater than total time
long remainingTimeInMillis = currentTimeInMillis < startTimeInMillis ?
        totalTimeInMilis : stopTimeInMillis - currentTimeInMillis;

// Update every second
long countDownIntervalInMillis = 1000;
// Alternatively you can adjust interval such that it is called only in integer percent changes
int remainingSteps = (int) (((double) remainingTimeInMillis / totalTimeInMilis) * 100);
long countDownIntervalInMillis = remainingTimeInMillis / remainingSteps;

mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(remainingTimeInMillis, countDownIntervalInMillis) {

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        int completedPercent = (int) ((1 - (double) millisUntilFinished / totalTimeInMilis) * 100);
        prBar.setProgress(completedPercent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        // Do what you want
        prBar.setProgress(100);
    }
};
mCountDownTimer.start();
```

Comment: I have tried all variations of your code and it works not correct on devices: progress bar's position always blinking from one position to another. the first position is random.

Comment: so if `long countDownIntervalInMillis = 1000;` - than blinking faster and if another variant - blinking slower

Comment: Can you try second way for calculating `countDownIntervalInMillis`? How many `remainingSteps` do you get  at the beginning? Plus, are your start and stop time in milliseconds?

Comment: depends on debugger information: all timestamps are in milliseconds, `remainingSteps = 6`, `startTimeInMillis = 1561920000000`, `stopTimeInMillis = 1561927200000`, `currentTimeInMillis = 1561926720005`, `totalTimeInMilis = 7200000`, `countDownIntervalInMillis = 79999`, `remainingTimeInMillis = 479995`.

Comment: I am not sure about blinking but your time values are too big for a test. Can you try with small values like `startTimeInMillis=1000`, `stopTimeInMillis=11000`, `currentTimeInMillis=6000` and `countDownIntervalInMillis=1000`? It should start at %50 and finish in 5 steps.

Comment: yes, it finished in 5 steps. But I need timestamps, so I have one more try but not with milliseconds, just timestamp: `startTimeInMillis = 1561983300`, `stopTimeInMillis = 1561989300`, `currentTime = 1561987983`, `totalTimeInMilis = 6000`, `remainingTimeInMillis = 1317`, `remainingSteps =  21` and problem is another - it looks like progressbar starts from a correct position but it done all of `remainingSteps` very fast - just in few seconds. why if it should be minutes / hours?